# Does PIGLatin support predicate pushdown with Parquet files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, parquet

I am evaluating Hadoop based storage options for my data set. Here's the current setup looks like:

- Thrift serialized objects with data size being with 1TB per day (with GZIP compression)
- Data will be accessed primarily by PIG scripts, and a few ad-hoc MR jobs
- Most of the PIG scripts would fetch the data for one calendar day for any given run, and would access only a small subset of columns from the Thrift object

I am planning to evaluate the storage options for

- Storage efficiency (amount of reduction in storage space required)
- Retrieval optimizations with PIG

I came across RC, ORC and Parquet. With some search, I could confirm that PIG14 onwards it can perform column pruning, partition pruning and predicate pushdown with ORC, but I could not come across any definite link explaining whether PIG can do the same with Parquet files. I came across https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4092, but out of the two links on this JIRA, one throws 404 and the other says "empty repository".

Can anyone please let me know if PIG can perform predicate pushdown for Parquet?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't. It is clearly considered to be implemented in the future but no signs of it yet.

I'd suggest to stick with ORC by now, it seems to have better Pig support.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.